# How to get Word Web App to open a linked doc in the same browser tab (updated)

Tags: 2010, office-web-apps

**Update:**

Digging through the Word Web App generated HTML, the link does indeed use `target="_blank"` as I suspected.

Link in context:

```
<a href="http://path/to/linked.docx?Web=1" target="_blank">
    <div title="http://path/to/linked.docx?Web=1" class="WACLink" style="left: 376px; top: 213px; width: 166px; height: 30px;"></div>
</a>
```

Does anyone know of a sane way to motivate SharePoint and/or the Word Web App to use `target="_self"` or `target="_top"` instead of `target="_blank"`? I just want to find a way for my readers to not get swamped with a multitude of browser tabs.

**Previous Request:**

I'm creating a set of Word docs that will have hyperlinks between them. Essentially, the main doc will be a list of links to the other docs. Each of the other docs will have a link back to the main doc. These docs are written in Microsoft Word 2013 and will open in the Word Web App in SharePoint 2010.

My goal is for the user to read all the docs in a single tab in the browser. Ie., click a link, the new doc will appear in the Word Web App in the same tab. Unfortunately, each time a link gets clicked, the browser opens a new Word Web App in a new tab. And I'm pretty sure my readers will quickly become lost and/or annoyed in the mass of tabs open in their browser.

Is there a way to make the Word Web App open the link in the same tab?

I attempted to solve this in Word by using the Target Frame button (in the Create Hyperlink dialog box and the Edit Hyperlink dialog box) when creating or editing the hyperlink. That brings up the Set Target Frame dialog box. I tried every frame option that dialog provided (Page Default (none), Same frame, Whole page, New window, Parent frame, and none), but each time, clicking the link in the Word Web App brings up the linked doc in a new tab. What other options would you people try?